# Go websocket jsonrpc browser connection close

Tags: go, websocket, json-rpc, gorilla

I have a WebSocket JSON-RPC server example that I want to use from a browser. When you access the URL "http:localhost:8080", the browser opens the WebSocket connection properly. But when the browser sends the WebSocket request, the server closes the WebSocket connection. I can't even see a trace of the RPC method being called on the server.

However, calling the server from a Go client works perfectly.

**server.go**

```js
package main

import (
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "net/rpc"
        "net/rpc/jsonrpc"
        "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

type Service struct{}

func (t *Service) Echo(req *string, res *string) error {
        log.Printf("Service.Echo")
        *res = *req
        log.Printf("Service.Echo req:%s res:%s", *req, *res)
        return nil 
}

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
        ReadBufferSize:  1024,
        WriteBufferSize: 1024,
}

func serveWS(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
        defer ws.Close()


        if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
        }   
        jsonrpc.ServeConn(ws.UnderlyingConn())
}

func main() {
        rpc.Register(new(Service))
        http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("web")))
        http.HandleFunc("/ws", serveWS)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**web/index.html**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws");
    ws.onopen = function(ev){
        alert("open");
    }
    ws.onmessage = function(ev){
        alert("message");
    }
    ws.onclose = function(ev){
        alert("close");
    }   

    function send() {
        msg = {
                method: "Service.Echo",
                params: "hello",
                id: 0
        };
        var s = JSON.stringify(msg);
        alert(s);
        ws.send(s);
    }   
</script>
</head> 
<body>          
<button onclick='send()'>Send</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

**client.go**

```js
package main

import (
        "log"
        "net/rpc/jsonrpc"
        "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

func main() {
        ws, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("ws://localhost:8080/ws", nil)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("dial:", err)
        }
        defer ws.Close()

        client := jsonrpc.NewClient(ws.UnderlyingConn())

        req := "hello"
        var res string
        err = client.Call("Service.Echo", &req, &res)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Service.Echo error:", err)
        }
        log.Printf("Service.Echo: req:%s res:%s", req, res)
}
```

Do you know what the problem could be?

Thank you very much.

Cheers

Comment: This question was also asked at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gorilla-web/CqBIuUCd0zA and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/4IKhYSuly9o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the server application calls `jsonrpc.ServeConn(ws.UnderlyingConn()) }` the server is switching from the WebSocket protocol to the [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) protocol.  The browser continues to use the [WebSocket](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) protocol. The connection is closed because one of the peers errors out reading a protocol that it does not expect.

The problem does not happen with the Go client application because this application also switches from the WebSocket protocol to the JSON-RPC protocol.

It is not possible to access the underlying network connection from a browser application.

It is possible to use the net/rpc package with [Codec](https://godoc.org/net/rpc#ServerCodec) written to use the WebSocket protocol. Another option is to write an adaptor to convert the message based WebSocket API to the stream expected by the net/rpc/jsonrpc server.

Comment: Ok, I see. But then, is there any way to use a websocket jsonrpc server from a browser?

Comment: It is not possible to use the JSON-RPC protocol from a browser.

Comment: @Alvaro You can implement a [Codec](https://godoc.org/net/rpc#ServerCodec) to use the net/rpc package from the browser.  Also, cross link those Google Groups postings so people don't waste time answering what's covered here.

Comment: Yes, the codec seems what I'm looking for. My final goal is just to send a JSON-RPC message through a Websocket connection. Do you know of any examples?

Comment: Write an adaptor to convert the message based WebSocket API to the stream expected by the net/rpc/json server.  Alternatively, copy the net/rpc/jsonrpc [server.go](https://golang.org/src/net/rpc/jsonrpc/server.go) and modify it to work with the message based WebSocket API.